# Why cant I connect more than 8000 clients to MQTT brokers via HAProxy?

Tags: tcp, mqtt, load-balancing, haproxy, scalability

I am trying to establish 10k client connections(potentially 100k) with my 2 MQTT brokers using HAProxy as a load balancer.

I have a working simulator(using Java Paho library) that can simulate 10k clients. On the same machine I run 2 MQTT brokers in docker. For LB im using another machine with virtual image of Ubuntu 16.04.

When I connect directly to a MQTT Broker those connections are established without a problem, however when I use HAProxy I only get around 8.8k connections, while the rest throw: Error at client{insert number here}: Connection lost (32109) - java.net.SocketException: Connection reset. When I connect simulator directly to a broker (Same machine) about 20k TCP connections open, however when I use load balancer only 17k do. This leaves me thinking that LB is causing the problem.

It is important to add that whenever I run the simulator I'm unable to use the browser (Cannot connect to the internet). I havent tested if this is browser only, but could that mean that I actually run out of ports or something similar and the real issue here is not in the LB?

Here is my HAProxy configuration:

```
global
    log /dev/log local0
    log /dev/log local1 notice
    maxconn 500000
    ulimit-n 500000 
    maxpipes 500000

defaults
    log global
    mode http
    timeout connect 3h  
    timeout client 3h
    timeout server 3h
    
listen mqtt
    bind *:8080
    mode tcp
    option tcplog
    option clitcpka
    balance leastconn
    server broker_1 address:1883 check
    server broker_2 address:1884 check

listen stats 
    bind 0.0.0.0:1936
    mode http
    stats enable
    stats hide-version
    stats realm Haproxy\ Statistics
    stats uri /
```

This is what MQTT broker shows for every successful/unsuccessful connection

```
...
//Successful connection
1613382861: New connection from xxx:32850 on port 1883.
1613382861: New client connected from xxx:60974 as 356 (p2, c1, k1200, u'admin').
...
//Unsuccessful connection
1613382699: New connection from xxx:42861 on port 1883.
1613382699: Client <unknown> closed its connection.
...
```

And this is what ulimit -a shows on LB machine.

```
core file size (blocks)         (-c) 0
data seg size (kb)              (-d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size (blocks)              (-f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 102355
max locked memory (kb)          (-l) 82000
max memory size (kb)            (-m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 500000
POSIX message queues (bytes)    (-q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size (kb)                 (-s) 8192
cpu time (seconds)              (-t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 500000
virtual memory (kb)             (-v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

Note: The LB process has the same limits.

I followed various tutorials and increased open file limit as well as port limit and TCP header size, etc. The number of connected users increased from 2.8k to about 8.5-9k (Which is still way lower than the 300k author of the tutorial had). ss -s command shows about 17000ish TCP and inet connections.

Any pointers would greatly help!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can't do a normal LB of MQTT traffic, as you can't "pin" the connection based on the MQTT Topic.  If you send in a SUBSCRIBE to Broker1 for Topic "test/blatt/#", but the next client PUBLISHes to Broker2 "test/blatt/foo", then if the two brokers are not bridged, your first subscriber will never get that message.

If your clients are terminating the TCP connection sometime after the CONNECT, or the HAproxy is round-robin'ing the packets between the two brokers, you will get errors like this.  You need to somehow persist the connections, and I don't know how you do that with HAproxy. Non-free LB's like A10 Thunder or F5 LTM can persist TCP connections...but you still need the MQTT brokers bridged for it all to work.

Comment: I think the clients stay connected. I ran a simulation of 5k clients and they stayed connected untill I turned them off. I also connected them and published data every 10s and everything worked perfectly. I ran the broker on a seperate machine (I changed ulimit -n and port size, etc.) and the number of connected clients jumped from 2800 to about 8.5-9k. Right now Im thinking theres a port exhaustion issue or something else bottlenecking the load balancer but cant figure out what.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was running out of resources on my computer.

I moved simulator to another machine and managed to get 15k connections running. Due to resource limits I cant get more than that. Computer thats running the serverside uses 20/32GB of RAM and the computer running simulator used 32/32GB for approx 15k devices. Now I see why running both on the same computer is not an option.